# Performance considerations for table design of chat service

Tags: mysql

We are implementing a chat service, and I'd like some input on table design. Our service uses MySQL, and our DB has 2 tables, Threads and Messages. Threads table stores all the chat threads, and Messages table stores all the messages. A chat thread can have multiple messages, while a message belong to only one thread. Each message is identified by a column in Messages table called messageId.

We need to get the messageId of the last message of each thread from time to time in our service. I can see 2 options:

```
1 add a column called lastMessageId to Threads to keep track of the last message; each time a message is inserted into Messages table, we need to update Threads table as well;

2 each time we need the last message's id, perform a query on Messages table to find the last message;
```

Which option should I take, and why?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for option 2, below are the reason.

1. You said that u need last message id time to time which means not so frequent. 
   Making a query time to time is less intensive than making an Update operation on every insert.
2. You can further fine tune your query by creating indexes on Messages Table.